# Will Jaunt web scraper be capable of scraping this javascript site

Tags: java, web-scraping

I have never done web scraping before, actually just 3 hours ago I google the word web scraping to see what it means... so this is my level of competence on the subject, but I have a task to scrape some numbers for different football matches of this website "betstars.uk" and from what I see it is a javascript website (is it ?) which makes the already hard task for me even harder, so can Jaunt tool for JAVA do this job or I need something else? I am asking because to avoid spending more than an hour learning how to use it just to find out it can't do the job

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I cannot load the website so I can't tell you if it uses javascript to load content or not.
It's impossible to scrape a javascript based website with Jaunt because it's a basic web scraper library and it doesnt load javascript at all. Though, in case the site uses javascript indeed, you could use htmlUnit to load javascript content and scrape the information you need.
Here is an easy tutorial on [How to Scrape Javascript in Java](http://www.scrapingauthority.com/2016/08/08/how-to-scrape-javascript-in-java/)

Comment: I set up this htmlUnit in Eclipse and it's working but I still don't know how to use it, the tutorial didn't help much

Comment: Could you tell me exactly what you don't know how to do?

Comment: I try to use the example code given in that tutorial for my purpose but when I paste this `List<HtmlAnchor> teams = (List) page.getByXPath("//td[@class='team']");` it gives me error "page" can not be resolved, and the other thing that I don't know is what should i put on the place of "//td[@class='team']", I know how to turn on the inspector in firefox and see the HTML code for different elements in the site but I don't know what to paste in my program